# how to select the unique id count for repeated id that have a specific value

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, count, having-clause

for example if i have this table

```
 report_date     id    customerCount    orderNr
  2020-02-20    123        12              10
  2020-02-19    123        18              11
  2020-02-18    123        0               12
  2020-02-20    321        0               0
  2020-02-19    321        0               0
  2020-02-18    321        0               0
  2020-02-20    456        17              13
  2020-02-19    456        0               0
  2020-02-18    456        15              14
  2020-02-20    654        0               0
  2020-02-19    654        0               0
  2020-02-18    654        0               0
```

i want to select the count of id that all of its rows are customerCount = 0 and orderNr = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To list all the `id`s, you can use aggregation and `having`. Boolean aggregation comes handy to express the constraints:

```
select id
from mytable
group by id
having bool_and(customerCount = 0) and bool_and(order_nr = 0)
```

If you want to count how many `id`s satisfy the conditions, you can add another level of aggregation:

```
select count(*) cnt
from (
    select id
    from mytable
    group by id
    having bool_and(customerCount = 0) and bool_and(order_nr = 0)
) t
```

Answer (score 1):

One method uses two levels of aggregation:

```
select count(*)
from (select id
      from t
      group by id
      having max(customerCount) = 0 and max(orderNr) = 0
     ) i;
```

Note:  This assumes that the values are never negative, which seems quite reasonable given the example values and naming.

Another method uses `not exists`:

```
select count(distinct id)
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.id = t.id and
                        (t2.customerCount <> 0 or t.orderNr <> 0)
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(table.id)
from table 
where customerCount = 0 and orderNr = 0
group by table.id
```